# request attribute unable to access in spring micro service

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets

I am setting up request attribute in overridden method `doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)` of class `OncePerRequestFilter` but i am unable to get request attribute in my service.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
      HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      ....
      .....
      httpServletRequest.setAttribute("testing","testing");
       filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

    }
}


 @RequestMapping(
      value = "/index/{index:.+}",
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
  public ResponseEntity<RestApiModelResponse> getIndex(
      @PathVariable String index,
     HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
      throws Exception {
    var test = httpServletRequest.getAttribute("testing");

}
```

Here, I am getting null in test variable..

Answer (score 0):

You need to define filter as [@Component](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
```

> In order for Spring to be able to recognize a filter, we needed to define it as a bean with the @Component annotation

Comment: even after adding @Component still getting null value in test variable

Comment: @moulali make sure filter is picked by componen scan